# JPA query to combine two tables via similar primary key

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, jpql

My query is :

```java
@Query("SELECT new someDTO(a.teamname, a.teamstat1, a.teamstat2)"
      +"FROM Teamentity a, League l join l.players p join p.team t where upper(t.teamName) like concat('%', upper(a.teamname),'%')")
```

The team names in both tables are similar but not entirely the same, some are shortened named versions of the other.

When calling this I am only getting results for some SELECT columns, and others are empty.

Is there a reason for this? Could the where statement be blocking the rest of data coming through?